# Multiple Queries issue

Tags: mysql

This is part C and MySQL code.
I'd like the database to change in the following ways
update table char_info, update table chars, and delete a row from table clan_info.

However for some reason it only does what the last query tells it to do.

Any way to make all 3 work?

```
if (curClan.treasure.debt > 3) {            
    sprintf(buf, "DELETE FROM clan_info WHERE  clanID='%d'",i);
    sprintf(buf,"UPDATE char_info SET clan='0', clan_rank='0', clan_serial='0' WHERE clan='%d'",i);
    sprintf(buf,"UPDATE chars SET clan='0', clan_rank='0', clan_serial='0' WHERE clan='%d'",i);    
}
```

Comment: Where/how are you actually executing these queries?

Comment: I assume you didn't consider that **maybe** you were overwriting `buf` each time you run the `sprintf`, so `buf` only contains the last query when you come to execute `buf`.

Comment: Assuming you are using a multi_query() you will also need to place a semi colon at the end of the first and second query.

Comment: I've mentioned that it executes the very last buf, however it turned out not to be so. After moving  sprintf(buf, "DELETE FROM clan_info WHERE  clanID='%d'",i); to bottom, only it got executed. So the delete statement works.